# AWS Amplify GraphQL - allow owner to create, but only if he belongs to a certain group

Tags: api, graphql, crud, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Suppose I have three user groups: `admin`, `doctor`, and `patient`

I want both `admin` and `doctor` to be able to create the type `Appointment`, but I want to forbid `patient` to do it. To simplify let's suppose that anyone from the 3 groups can read any `Appointment`.

Here's the tricky part:

For each `Appointment` already created I want the admin group be able to update it and delete it (even if the `admin` is not the owner of that `Appointment`), but for the `doctor` group I want to only allow access to update if the doctor is the owner of the appointment. **Besides `admin`, I want to let only users in the `doctor` group to be able to create `Appointment`**. The part in bold is what I'm being unable to do. In the schema I have below, patients are also able to create appointments.

How do I change it so that only `doctor` and `admin` can create?

Note: in `Appointment` the create operation for `owner` must be there, otherwise, the `clientId` field doesn't auto-populate with the owner id, and I need that. I think that `create` operation is actually what's creating my problem, but I see no way around.

```
type Doctor
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [create, update, delete] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "doctorId", operations: [update] }
    ]
  )
  @key(fields: ["doctorId"]) {
  doctorId: ID! # This ID won't be auto-populated (it's the cognito pool ID of the doctor)
  name: String!
  appointments: [Appointment]
    @connection(keyName: "byDoctor", fields: ["doctorId"])
  createdAt: String
}

type Patient
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [create, update, delete] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "patientId", operations: [update] }
    ]
  )
  @key(fields: ["patientId"]) {
  patientId: ID! # This ID won't be auto-populated (it's the cognito pool ID of the patient)
  name: String!
  appointments: [Appointment]
    @connection(keyName: "byPatient", fields: ["patientId"])
  createdAt: String
}

type Appointment
  @model
  @auth(
    rules: [
      { allow: private, operations: [read] }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["admin"], operations: [create, update, delete] }
      { allow: groups, groups: ["doctor"], operations: [create, read] }
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "doctorId", operations: [create, update] }
    ]
  )
  @key(
    name: "byDoctor"
    fields: ["doctorId", "createdAt"]
    queryField: "appointmentsByDoctorId"
  )
  @key(
    name: "byPatient"
    fields: ["patientId", "createdAt"]
    queryField: "appointmentsByPatientId"
  ) {
  id: ID!
  doctorId: ID # Auto-populated with cognito pool ID of the doctor
  patientId: ID!
  doctor: Doctor @connection(fields: ["doctorId"])
  patient: Patient @connection(fields: ["patientId"])
  createdAt: String
}
```

And here's an illustration of the problem:

```
# -- Initially authenticated as a user in `admin` group --
# Result: initially empty (which is expected)
query ListAppointments {
  listAppointments {
    items {
      id
      doctorId
      patientId
    }
  }
}

# Result: succeeds (which is expected)
mutation CreateDoctor {
  createDoctor(input: {
    doctorId: "66a2b382-952d-4e8d-a25e-b8d1876e8017" # arbitrary
    name: "Doctor 1"
  }) {
    doctorId
    name
  }
}

# Result: succeeds (which is expected)
mutation CreatePatient {
  createPatient(input: {
    patientId: "2d9366cd-165b-4437-a910-647900df0587" # arbitrary
    name: "Bar Patient"
  }) {
    patientId
    name
  }
}

# -- Switching auth to user in `doctor` group --
# Result: succeeds (which is expected)
# If we run `ListAppointments` now, the appointment created is there
mutation CreateAppointmentByDoctor {
  createAppointment(input: {
    patientId: "8a2b382-952d-4e8d-a25e-b8d187000000" # arbitrary
  }) {
    id
  }
}

# -- Switching auth to user in `patient` group --
# Result: succeeds (which is NOT expected)
# If we run `ListAppointments` now, there are two appointments there,
# including this one created by a client
mutation CreateAppointmentByPatient {
  createAppointment(input: {
    patientId: "8a2b382-952d-4e8d-a25e-b8d187001000" #arbitrary
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a custom resolver to handle this case:

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/resolvers

If you want some code examples look at the build folder inside the api folder in the project.

Amplify templates the code of the resolvers based on the directives you're putting in the schema.

You can reuse part of this code to implement your use case in a custom resolver.

Comment: Yup, I ended up using a Lambda resolver with @function

Comment: That will work but will be slightly slower (like 100-200ms) than if you do it in VLT in the resolvers. VLT is painful in the beginning but after you get used to it it just flows